# Why does my program only change some of the letters

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

So, I am trying to make a ROT13decoder, and this is what I  have so far. Only some of the letters change though and I am not sure why. I'm very new to programming. I am just trying to figure out how to read in files, and write to files. So far that part works, but yeah it doesn't change all the letters in the original file, just some of them. I would really appreciate any feedback.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//the letters in the secretMessage file are "Lbh unir gb fgnl va funcr. Zl tenaqzbgure, fur fgnegrq jnyxvat svir zvyrf n qnl jura fur jnf 60. Fur’f 97 gbqnl naq jr qba’g xabj jurer gur uryy fur vf
//
//
//and this is what it outputs to the decodedMessage file "Lbh haie gb fgal ia fhace. Ml geaadmbghee, fhe fgaeged jalkiag fiie milef a dal jhea fhe jaf 60. Fhe’f 97 gbdal aad je dba’g kabj jheee ghe hell fhe if.

using namespace std;


int main(){
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("secretMessage.txt");
    fout.open("decodedMessage.txt");


    char c = 0;



    while (!fin.eof()){
        c = fin.get();
        if (c == 'a')c = 'n';
        if (c == 'b')c = 'o';
        if (c == 'c')c = 'p';
        if (c == 'd')c = 'q';
        if (c == 'e')c = 'r';
        if (c == 'f')c = 's';
        if (c == 'g')c = 't';
        if (c == 'h')c = 'u';
        if (c == 'i')c = 'v';
        if (c == 'j')c = 'w';
        if (c == 'k')c = 'x';
        if (c == 'l')c = 'y';
        if (c == 'm')c = 'z';
        if (c == 'n')c = 'a';
        if (c == 'o')c = 'b';
        if (c == 'p')c = 'c';
        if (c == 'q')c = 'd';
        if (c == 'r')c = 'e';
        if (c == 's')c = 'f';
        if (c == 't')c = 'g';
        if (c == 'u')c = 'h';
        if (c == 'v')c = 'i';
        if (c == 'w')c = 'j';
        if (c == 'x')c = 'k';
        if (c == 'y')c = 'l';
        if (c == 'z')c = 'm';


        if (c == 'A')c = 'N';
        if (c == 'B')c = 'O';
        if (c == 'C')c = 'P';
        if (c == 'D')c = 'Q';
        if (c == 'E')c = 'R';
        if (c == 'F')c = 'S';
        if (c == 'G')c = 'T';
        if (c == 'H')c = 'U';
        if (c == 'I')c = 'V';
        if (c == 'J')c = 'W';
        if (c == 'K')c = 'X';
        if (c == 'L')c = 'Y';
        if (c == 'M')c = 'Z';
        if (c == 'N')c = 'A';
        if (c == 'O')c = 'B';
        if (c == 'P')c = 'C';
        if (c == 'Q')c = 'D';
        if (c == 'R')c = 'E';
        if (c == 'S')c = 'F';
        if (c == 'T')c = 'G';
        if (c == 'U')c = 'H';
        if (c == 'V')c = 'I';
        if (c == 'W')c = 'J';
        if (c == 'X')c = 'K';
        if (c == 'Y')c = 'L';
        if (c == 'Z')c = 'M';
        cout << c;
        if (!fin.eof())fout << c;
    }


    fin.close();
    fout.close();



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most letters in your example will be flipped twice.  You either need to add a whole lot of 'else' commands or use a switch statement.

```
if (c == 'a')c = 'n';
else if (c == 'b')c = 'o';
```

There is a better, mathematical method; but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 3):

You have a logic error.  If you start with "a" the first IF turns it into "n" and a later IF turns it back into "a".

Have a look at the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

you should not use `if` conditions everywhere as each of them will be checked as you have a new row. Suppose your character is `l` then your if statement changes the letter to `y` but the condition for `y` is also checked so the character is changed back to `l`. So in fact your code is not *not* changing some of the letters, it is changing them *twice*.

You should be able to cure this using `else if` for the subsequent entries so that when one is true the other ones don't get checked, or you could use a `switch case`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a single letter encoded in ROT13. If you encode it twice, you end up with the original letter again, which makes encoding and decoding ROT13 practically the same.

Now take for example the letter 'a'. What you are doing above in your code is

```
if (c == 'a') c = 'n';
...
if (c == 'n') c = 'a';
```

So for the first half of the letters above (a to m), you're encoding twice, getting the same letter again. Only for the lower half of the letters the encoding is only done once.

One solution to this would be to change your statements to something like

```
if (c == 'a') { c = 'n'; continue; }
```

This would skip the rest of the code in case of a match and `continue` with the next loop iteration.